# Will transferring saves between versions of Skyrim mess up the save?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm about to transfer saves from my PC to my new bulky PC. I have 1.7 on my 1st computer and 1.9 on my bulky computer.

Will it mess up my save when I transfer?

Comment: It didnt mess up mine. That's not to say it's impossible, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Transferring savegames towards a newer version of the game is guaranteed to be riskless.**

Since Skyrim is mostly used through Steam, *pretty much all the players playing Skyrim had at some point to update the game* (or have it automatically updated through Steam).

If in doing so you were at risk to lose your savegames, this would have resulted in thousands of upset players, and would probably have ended in riots and Bethesda losing their heads! :)

**When updating games, game studios take extreme care of backward compatibility** (as they don't want to upset people) *and thus don't remove content, only add it* (removing content can happen, but then they have put fixes and patches to actually make your savegame compatible).

Going the other way around is a different story as some things in a 1.9 version of the game might not be here in a 1.7 version because it was added in the meantime, and thus could make the savegames not readable by the older version of the game.

**But as said above, going from an older version to a newer is risk-less and can be done without problem.**

Make sure though you are making a backup copy just in case, even when just copying from a computer to another one with the same version. Errors can happen, and not all computers are created equal! :)

---

**There is also the question of mods. Some of them can make savegames unstable or incompatible when removed.**
If you had mods on the older computer, make sure to replicate the same modded environment on the new one, or you might risk making the savegame crashing (but this has nothing to do with the version difference).

As stated, this is a risk, it might never happen, and most mods/plugins will probably not create any issue. But modding a game is a delicate and fragile construction, so making sure it is the same helps preventing risks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're copying save files, then there's no way you can mess up the original save file by loading a copy in a newer version.

Make a backup of your save, then try to load it on the new computer. If it doesn't load right on the new computer, at least the save will still run fine on the previous computer.